# Deploy assemblies into GAC using SharePoint package

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, solution-package, farm-solution, assembly-references

If I have3rd party assemblies in the bin directory of the project and  want to deploy them to GAC using SharePoint WSP, how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

- Go to `Package.package` in your project and double-click it.
- Click the "Advanced" tab
- Click "Add" and "Add Existing Assembly.."
- Click the "triple-dots (...)"
- Navigate to your project folder and then to the `.dll` in the bin-folder and click "Open"

That should be it